# Arduino <--> Raspberry PiCM4 Serial communication very slow

Tags: python, c++, serial-port, esp8266, uart

I want to use a raspberry Pi to communicate to my ESP8266 D1 mini over Serial. Currently i have a steppermotor attached to my ESP8266. For test purposes, I just write a PWM frequency from my Raspberry Pi to the ESP8266 which is then used as "steps" for my steppermotor.

Everything works, but unfortunately if I write a new value to the ESP8266, the frequency changes roughly 1 second after my input. I think it has something to do with the buffer, but I am not sure if the problem is on the raspberry-side or on the ESP8266-side.

As a feedback, I just print the received values back to my raspberry over serial as a confirmation that the values change. If I write a value value of roughly less than 99999999, the feedback value is identical. Unfortunately, if I send for example "9582665835" as a value, I receive "992731243" as a feedback. It just happens if the value is very big and I think I made some mistakes in converting the value properly. Maybe someone knows also a solution for that.

**Code on Raspberry-side:**

```
import serial
import time

SerialPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 500000, timeout=1)
cmd = 5000
cmd = str(cmd).encode()
SerialPort.write(cmd)

time.sleep(0.01)

DataReceived = SerialPort.readline().decode().strip()
print(DataReceived)
```

**Code on ESP8266-side**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <HighPowerStepperDriver.h>
HighPowerStepperDriver Driver;

const uint8_t CSPin = 15;
const uint8_t PWMPIN = 0;

int receivedRawValue = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(500000);
 SPI.begin();
 Driver.setChipSelectPin(CSPin);
 pinMode(PWMPIN, OUTPUT);
 analogWrite(PWMPIN, 128);

 delay(1);

 Driver.resetSettings();
 Driver.clearStatus();

 Driver.setCurrentMilliamps36v4(250);

 Driver.setStepMode(HPSDStepMode::MicroStep8);

 Driver.enableDriver();
 Driver.setDirection(0);
}

void loop()
{
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   receivedRawValue = Serial.parseInt(); // Lese die empfangene Zahl
  analogWriteFreq(receivedRawValue);
  Serial.println(receivedRawValue);
}
}


//https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

Comment: Be cautious. 9582665835 is a pretty big number that probably doesn't fit in an `int`.

Comment: In fact, when truncated to 32 bit, 9582665835 (0x2 3B2B E06B) can become 992731243 (0x3B2B E06B), so my shot-in-the-dark comment looks like it might have some credibility.

Comment: What kind of serial are you using?  RS232?  RS485?  USB 1.0?  USB 2?  USB 3.0?

Comment: In Arduino, `int` is 16-bit long for Arduino Uno (classic 8-bit MCUs), and 32-bit long for ESP32/8266 or any 16-bit MCU. `ParseInt()` can only handle up to 32-bit data, and `9582665835` is more than 32-bit. Unlike python, when writing code in C/C++, you need to aware the data type that you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

`serial.parseInt()` waits for non-numeric character as a delimiter or a timeout.The default delay is around 1 sec. You can fix this by reducing the timeout using `serial.setTimeout()` or sending a non-numeric after you send then int.